# How can I change id in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have this js vars:

```
tab[1] = '<TR id="1"><TD>1</TD><TD>name</TD><TD >1</TD><TD>100.00</TD></TR>';
tab[2] = '<TR id="2"><TD>2</TD><TD>name</TD><TD >1</TD><TD>100.00</TD></TR>';
tab[3] = '<TR id="5"><TD>5</TD><TD>name</TD><TD >1</TD><TD>100.00</TD></TR>';
tab[4] = '<TR id="7"><TD>7</TD><TD>name</TD><TD >1</TD><TD>100.00</TD></TR>';
```

How can I use js replace to replace ID and first column in each of this vars?

The result should look like this:

```
tab[1] = '<TR id="1"><TD>1</TD><TD>name</TD><TD >1</TD><TD>100.00</TD></TR>';
tab[2] = '<TR id="2"><TD>2</TD><TD>name</TD><TD >1</TD><TD>100.00</TD></TR>';
tab[3] = '<TR id="3"><TD>3</TD><TD>name</TD><TD >1</TD><TD>100.00</TD></TR>';
tab[4] = '<TR id="4"><TD>4</TD><TD>name</TD><TD >1</TD><TD>100.00</TD></TR>';
```

@edit

I tried with simple replace:

```
`tab[i]=tab[i].replace('id="'+k+'"><TD>'+k+'</TD>', 'id="'+i+'"><TD>'+i+'</TD>');`
```

but id may be any digit so it not work in all cases :/

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using jquery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i ++) {
  tab[i] = $(tab[i]).find("tr").first().attr("id", "id_" + i);
}
```

What this does:

1. Create jquery objects from the html string: `$(tab[i])`
2. Find the first tr object: `.find("tr").first()`
3. Set the attribute "id" of the object to "id_" + i: `.attr("id", "id_" + i)`

I added "id_" because [ids and classes starting with a number are invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) and may be ignored by a browser.

This will result in your array containing jquery objects instead of strings, but you can add them to your DOM just like a string. If you need the result as a string for some reason, you can just add `.html()` to return a html String.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally feel the easiest way to do this would be *after* the HTML has been added to your document. An example:

```
table = document.getElementById('whatIsYourTablesIdBecauseIDontKnow =p');
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i ++) {
    table.rows[i].id = i + 1;
}
```

Even better would be that for whatever code you have that uses IDs, change it to select rows numerically; like I just did in that for loop.